# Unable to select worksheet by name

Tags: vba

I'm trying to assign the first sheet of the current workbook to sheet object, but I get a Runtime error "91", Object variable or with block variable not set.

```
Sub Test
Dim InSheet as Worksheet
InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

However I'm able to loop through the worksheet collection like so

```
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
Debug.Print ws.Name
Next
```

Sheets("Sheet1") or Sheets(1) do not work. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the workbook has a sheet named "Sheet1", you just need to use `Set`, and better still, if you know it's a worksheet, and not a chart sheet, use `Worksheets`:

```
Sub Test
Dim InSheet as Worksheet
Set InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

But you might find it easier to give the sheet a `CodeName` like `InSheet` in the properties window, and then you can just refer to it in code, regardless of whether somebody changes its name, like so:

```
Sub Test
  Debug.Print InSheet.Name
End Sub
```